# Reasons for creating an Index for a string field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

When I create an Index on a string-type field in MongoDB I get no significant speed boost from it. In fact, when I use the query:

```
db.movies.find({plot: /some text/}).explain("executionStats")
```

An Index is slowing down the query by 30-50% in my Database (~55k Docs).

I know, that I can use a "text" Index, which is working fine for me, but I was wondering, why you would create a "normal" Index on a string field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index on string fields will improve the performance of exact matches like,

```
db.movies.find({name: "some movie"})
```

Indexes will also be used for find queries with prefix expression,

```
db.movies.find({plot: /^begins with/})
```

Comment: Thanks! But when I search for {plot: /contains something/} is there a way to tell MongoDB NOT to use the index, because a simple COLLSCAN is faster in that case?

Comment: You can use [hints](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#cursor.hint) to force collection scan.
db.movies.find({plot: /contains something/}).hint( { $natural: 1 } )